# row from bootstrap table does not post value

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble when bootstrap table is installed. When I use data-toggle="table" to activate bootstrap I am not able to post checked value it always display NULL that means it is not checked . If I create normal table everything works great. 
Does anyone know how to solve this issue, is this a bug?

```
<form method="post" action="unos.php">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="izmjena">Izmjena</button>
<table data-toggle="table" data-show-columns="true" data-click-to-select="true" 
data-search="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-export="true" >


<tr> 
  <th data-field="artikli" data-checkbox="true" name="artikli"> </th>
  <th data-field="sifra" data-sortable="true">Sifra</th>
  <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Naziv</th>
</tr> 

$q = $conn->query($sql);
while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>

<tr>           
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="artikli" value="<?php echo $r['ArtId'];?>"></td>
  <td><?=$r['ArtSifra'] ?></td>
  <td><?=$r['ArtNaziv'] ?></td>
</tr>                                                       
<?php endwhile;  ?>
</table>
</form>
```

// unos.php file

```
if (isset($_POST["izmjena"])) {

$id=(!empty($_POST["artikli"])) ? $_POST["artikli"] : ''; 

var_dump($id);

echo $id;

}
```

Comment: not sure what an "izmjena" is, but I don't see the field set anywhere within your given code. If you want for a checkbox to allow multiple values to be sent to the server, change `<input type="checkbox" name="artikli" value="<?php echo $r['ArtId'];?>">` to `<input type="checkbox" name="artikli[]" value="<?php echo $r['ArtId'];?>" />`

Comment: Izmjena is button. <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="izmjena">Izmjena</button> I want to send only one value

Comment: The button should be inside your form. Is it?

Comment: it is inside form.. i just forget to put it here

Comment: Dupe: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15346